# Underlying set of an R-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules

What is meant by the underlying set of an $R$-module, say $M$? Does it mean $M$ without the module structure, and just looked at as a set, and what does it mean to drop its module structure? Or does it mean the set used to generate $M$, and what does that look like?

There reason I ask is because I'm asked to write down what the forgetful functor $G: R\text{-mods} \to Sets$, defined by sending $R$-mods to their underlying sets, does to morphisms. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes; remember that a module is a set, together with operations that make it into an abelian group, and a function $R\times M\to M$ that makes it into a module. The “underlying set” of the monoid is just the set, “forgetting” *(hence “Forgetful functor”) the abelian group operations and the scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin So the homomorphism from $M$ to $N$ just becomes a function from $M$ to $N$? But how would that be written explicitly?

Comment: @user439126 If one wanted to be more explicit, one should say "Let $(M,\cdot, +, 0)$ be an $R$-module..." Then, the object part of the "forgetful" functor would simply be the projection $(M,\cdot,+,0)\mapsto M$. It is very common to notationally conflate the name of an algebraic structure with its underlying set. As an exercise or when first learning a new topic, I would encourage you to try to write things out as explicitly as possible to get a feel for what is usually suppressed (and why...)

Comment: @Derek Elkins So, now I understand the object part. But what I don't understand is the morphism part. I'm not sure how a homomorphism would get mapped to a function of sets in this context

Comment: The forgetful functor takes module homomorphisms and only “remembers” that they are maps from the set $M$ to the set $N$. That’s what a morphism is, after all: a **function** $f\colon M\to N$... which satisfies some properties. The forgetful functor “forgets” that the map satisfies those properties (even though it still does).